# Get TimePicker start time from textview

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I have a TimePicker. When the user first clicks on the TimePicker it displays the Time is is. So they I click on the TimePicker at 11:40 the TimePicker will show 11:40 until they change it to the time they want. So say they pick the time 1:00. I have that save to a textview for them to see. The TextView is call startime. What I want is if they were to click on the same time picker again, instead of it showing the time it is when it was clicked, I want it to show the time the text view is displaying.

For example: I click on the TimePicker and it shows the time as 11:14 because that what time it is. I now set the time picker to 1:00, click ok and it saves 1:00 to the textview. When I click on the TimePicker again I now want it to say 1:00 matching the Textview instead of 11:14 the real time of day. How do I do this Thanks!

Time Picker Code:

```
    // Method To See What Happens When StartTime Is Clicked//
    public void OnClick_StartTime(View v) {

    // Vibrates For 50 Mill//
    vibe.vibrate(50);

    // Create Calender Instance//
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Creates New Time Picker Dialog//
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            Change.this,
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            false
    );
    timePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TIMEPICKER_TAG);

    // Puts It Into 12 Hour Format//
    timePickerDialog.setOnTimeSetListener(new  
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout, 
        int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            // Define 24 Hour Of Day//
            int military_hour_start= hourOfDay;

            // If Hour Equals Zero Set It To 24//
            if (military_hour_start == 0) {

                // Sets hour to 24//
                military_hour_start = 24;
            }

            // 24 Hour Format Time And Minute String//
            military_start_time = String.valueOf(military_hour_start) + 
            ":" + minute;

            // Sets Time 12 Hour Format//
            String timeSet;
            if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                hourOfDay -= 12;
                timeSet = "PM";
            } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                hourOfDay += 12;
                timeSet = "AM";
            } else if (hourOfDay == 12)
                timeSet = "PM";
            else
                timeSet = "AM";

            String min;
            if (minute < 10)
                min = "0" + minute;
            else
                min = String.valueOf(minute);

            // Append in a StringBuilder//
            aTime = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ':' + min + " " + 
            timeSet;
            starttime.setText(aTime);

            // Calls Calculate Total Time Method//
            Calculate_TotalTime();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(starttime.getText().toString().equals("")
   {
     //Your current code which fires the TimePickerDialog

   }
 else  //There is some value stored in starttime
   {
      //call below functions on timepickerDialog object. 
      //get hour min sec from starttime
     timePickerDialog.setCurrentHour(hour);
     timePickerDialog.setCurrentMinute(min);
     timePickerDialog.setCurrentSecond(sec);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calling code, bundle up the time you want displayed (ex. 1:00):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("hour", 1);
b.putInt("minute", 0);

dlgFrag = new TimePickerFragment();
dlgFrag.setArguments(b);
dlgFrag.show(..., ...);
```

In your `TimePickerDialog` class, override the `onCreateDialog(Bundle b)` to read in the hour/minute arguments:

```
private int _hour;
private int _minute;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle b_) {
    Bundle bundle_ = getArguments();
    if (bundle_ != null) {
        _hourOfDay = bundle_.getInt("hour");
        _minute = bundle_.getInt("minute");
    }

    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    if (_hourOfDay <= 0 || _minute <= 0) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        _hourOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        _minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, _hourOfDay, _minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```